# bash script to process stdin in chunks using dd and redirections

Tags: bash, split, io-redirection, dd

I came across an old bash script, which splits data from stdin.
When run as `seq 1234 | ./test_dd_a.sh`, the files temp.1 to temp.5 are created. As it  progress, it shows:

```
processing part 1
...
processing part 5
processing part 6
extraneous temp.6 will be deleted...
```

Here's the code:

```
i=1
while true
do
    {
        echo "processing part $i" 1>&2
        dd bs=1k count=1 of="temp.$i" 2>&3
    } 3>&1 | grep -q '^0+0 ' && {
        echo "extraneous temp.$i will be deleted..."
        rm "temp.$i"
        break
    }
    i=`expr $i + 1`
done
```

I would like to use that as a basis for a script which copies data from stdin to stdout, something like the code below. However, when run in the same manner it does not yet give any output to stdout, but it does show progress and stops when expected.

```
i=1
while true
do
    {
        echo "processing part $i" 1>&2
        dd bs=1k count=1  2>&3
    } 3>&1 | grep -q '^0+0 ' && {
        break
    }
    i=`expr $i + 1`
done
```

I would like to get the above working with minimal changes and believe it can be done with some additional tinkering with the redirections.
Assume pv, split or similar commands are not available.

Comment: FYI, `i=$(expr $i + 1)` is much slower to run compared to `i=$((i+1))`, and not substantially more portable (as `$(( ))` is guaranteed to be built into all POSIX-compliant shells, since the original publication of POSIX.2 in 1992).

Comment: BTW, the first scriptlet would be less sensitive to changes in undocumented behavior if it just looked at whether the part just written by `dd` was empty, instead of trying to parse its stderr.

Comment: Also, you tagged this as `bash`; does that mean bash-only extensions are acceptable?

Comment: (qualifying one of the above claims: `dd`'s stderr messages _are_ subject to documented guarantees, but only in the `POSIX` locale).

Comment: BTW, note the `0[+]0` in my answer -- without it being `[+]` instead of just bare `+`, the string `00` matches, since `+` is a modifier in regex syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
i=1
while :; do
  echo "processing part $i" 1>&2
  if { LC_ALL=POSIX dd bs=1k count=1 2>&3 >&4; } 3>&1 | grep -qe '^0[+]0 '; then
    break
  fi
  i=$(( i + 1 ))
done 4>&1
```

Comment: It does not work for me. Nothing goes to stdout.

Comment: @fundamental, see the current version of the code working successfully in the online interpreter at https://ideone.com/nZhohd

Comment: Nice one! Thank you.